# how to get the record counts of all tables in MySQL Database based on condition

Tags: mysql, database

I Have tried this query

```
SELECT table_name, 
       table_rows
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mydb';
```

with this query I can able to get all the tables record counts available in my database but I failed to get record  based on this condition where
 `date_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;`

where to change the query to get all the row_counts based on the condition for all tables thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just have to generate the above query for each table in your db. You could feed the generation process with `information_scheme.TABLES` data and accumulate the results.

Comment: i already tried whatever you are telling, i can able to get all records for all tables my intention is based on condition i want the record count of all tables

Comment: `i already tried whatever you are telling` You either did it and succeeded, or you dont understand what im saying.

Comment: based on condition i am not getting the record count

Comment: If you tried what i'm telling you, then maybe add this to the question so we can start troubleshooting :) You basically have to repeat the same query for each table, include whatever `where` clause you like

Comment: I think what @Techno was suggesting is that you take the list of tables produced from your `information_schema` query you've described in your question, and then execute a `SELECT` query for each table it returns.  You could do this in a stored procedure, for example.

Comment: but I have total of 210 tables in my database

Comment: `but I have total of 210 tables in my database ` Thats why i use the word `generate`. Use your programming language of choice(or stored procedure) to generate and execute all queries. Start by getting all your tables with information scheme, then generate all 210 queries and execute them

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can modify the query to get record counts for all tables based on a condition:

```
1. Dynamically construct a query for each table:
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ''', table_name, ''' AS table_name, COUNT(*) AS 
row_count FROM ', table_name, ' WHERE date_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 
DAY;') AS query
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mydb';

2.Execute each query using a prepared statement:
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).